# Precompiled Web App still uses "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

OK, I'm totally confused.  I need to update an old ASP.NET Web Application but I'm totally unfamiliar with Visual Studio...

The updated web app uses some DLLs which are compiled as part of the solution and placed in the web app 'Bin' folder.  Two of these DLLs require other files in the same folder.

My problem is that, even though I publish the web app (locally for now) with the option "Precompile during publishing", at run time these DLLs are copied to the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder without their supporting files.

Is there a way to have ASP.NET use the DLLs in the 'Bin' folder without copying them somewhere else?  Or is there a way to 'attach' the supporting files to the DLLs so that they get copied as well?

And no, I have no idea what I'm doing at this point...

I found this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3918305/854760) that is essentially the same thing (answers talk about properties I don't have).

Answer (score 0):

We ended up adding an `appSettings` key/value to `web.config` that the DLL use to find the required files.

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <appSettings>
    <add key="sExeFolder" value="C:\Project\Support_Files"/>
  </appSettings>
  ...
</configuration>
```